# How to play realtime binary stream through client speakers in HTML5

Tags: node.js, html, audio, binary-data, web-audio-api

I need help playing a binary stream to a client's speakers using the client's web browser. The stream is being recorded from a client's web browser and is sent to a NodeJS server using BinaryJS. I have successfully streamed the binary data back to the client from the server, but cannot figure out how to play it. I am using NodeJs, BinaryJS, webAudio API, and HTML5. I have also been testing with Firefox. Has anybody done this before? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an option for you, the simplest option would be to encode your data to a compressed format (say, mp3, ogg, opus, etc.), and simply put the URL in an `<audio>` tag.

[This](https://pedromtavares.wordpress.com/2012/12/28/streaming-audio-on-the-web-with-nodejs/) pages is a good introduction on how to stream mp3 from node.